# How do I include a STAR in an ICAO flight plan?

Tags: flight-planning, icao-sarps

Would it be in accordance with ICAO norms to include a STAR identification right after the airway name in the field 15 of the flight plan? Or should the connecting point between the airway and the STAR be included before the STAR?

Example without CP:

> R460 LKN R594 JAL5E

Example with CP:

> R460 LKN R594 JAL JAL5E

Answer (score 1):

ICAO Doc 4444 Appendix 3 has the clearest text (and an example):

> *Standard arrival route*
>
> The designator for the standard arrival route from the point of leaving the defined route to the point at which the approach procedure is initiated.
>
> *Note.— Standard arrival route need only be included where appropriate.*

Let's break down the language:

"The **designator** for the standard arrival route from the **point** of leaving the **defined route** to the **point** at which the approach procedure is initiated."

Which means:

(defined route – airway)
(last applicable point on airway)
(first point on STAR)
(STAR designator)

In the example given *(below),* both points are shared (FTM), similarly for the SID – emphasis mine:

> N0460F290 **LEK2B LEK UA6** FNE UA6 XMM/M078F330 UA6N PON UR10N CHW UA5 NTS DCT 4611N00412W DCT STG **UA5 FTM FATIM1A**

[image]
(Highlight mine.)